# Распознавание речи в python

Tags: python, распознавание-речи, google-speech-recognition

У меня есть небольшой скрипт на python который записывает речь в текст.Данный скрипт использует SpeechRecognition 3.8.1.Я хочу сделать так чтобы можно голосом сказать например : удалить слово номер 1 и данное слово удалиться из текста.

```
import speech_recognition as sr

r = sr.Recognizer()
with sr.Microphone(device_index=1) as source :
    print("Запись начата")
    audio = r.listen(source)

query = r.recognize_google(audio, language="ru-RU")
print("Ваш текст:" + query.lower())
```

Comment: Что Вы понимаете под удалением данного слова? Откуда оно должно удалиться? Здесь также уместен вопрос "зачем"?

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я понимаю, `r.recognize_google(audio, language="ru-RU")` возвращает вам строку, а следовательно вы можете использовать команду `.split()`, чтобы получить список из слов и, при необходимости убрать ненужные элементы(в данном случае индекс слова в списке и будет тем самым "номером" для управления), а затем из получившегося списка записать итоговую строку.